# Non - Nilpotent Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am studying the theorem that " The nil radical of a ring R is the intersection of the prime ideals of R".

I understand that the set of nilpotent elements of R form an ideal.

What can we say about the set of non-nilpotent elements of R? It certainly contains 1, since 1 is not nilpotent, but is it closed under multiplication?

May you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Or in $\;\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z\;$ we have no non-zero nilpotent elements, yet $\;2\cdot3=0\;$ ...

Comment: Thank you very much. So, it means that it is not closed under multiplication.

Comment: Indeed it is not..

Comment: @DonAntonio Ok, it is clear now by this counter example. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb Z_6$ we have $2$ and $3$.

Comment: Fernandez Hidalgo Thank you. I was confused when I was reading the proof of the theorem, but it just fixes a non-nilpotent element and takes in consider the set of the powers of this element for every natural number which is clearly closed under multiplication.

Comment: oh yeah, that one is :)